# run windows service(srvany.exe) error,but run with psexec is ok

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I'm use dxgi to capture login screen,and set the process auto startup(use instsrv+srvany).
but when I call the code

```
    if (FAILED(hr = pAdapter->EnumOutputs(0, &pOutput)))
{
    printf("error:%x\n", hr);
    CLEAN_RETURN(hr);
}
```

the error code is DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE(0x887A0022).
and OpenInputDesktop return error(1)

if I use PsExec64.exe to run the process(PsExec64.exe -s -d -i dxgiSample.exe),it's ok.
so what's problem?

Comment: but service process have separate, not interactive Window Station. so try open/capture input desktop from service and must fail

Comment: Why is this tagged `PowerShell`??

Answer (score 0):

> instsrv+srvany

Run your application as a service.

Services run in [session 0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/ba-p/372473).

If you call [`IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiadapter-enumoutputs) in a Session `0` process, it returns `DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE`.

Comment: thanks,so how can I capture in session 0? switch to session 1?

Comment: @hello Could you share your use case for why want to capture login screen?